# Closing notepad in another way

Tags: c#, .net

Can I use SendMessage class (how) instead of SendKeys twice? I want to close and save that notepad.

```
public void EditTxtFile(string text)
{
    var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (p != null)
    {    
        //var handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
        SendKeys.SendWait(text);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm opening notepad in web browser.

Comment: Why is `p.WaitForInputIdle();` before `if (p != null)`?

Comment: @codroipo edited. I've just forgot to delte this line... lol

Answer (score 1):

You can see how you can use SendMessage in winforms [in this post on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/94e500c8-6d1b-43bf-9c04-9823597525bf/how-to-use-sendmessage-in-c?forum=winforms).

Also I would personally just do this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);
```

Comment: I'm using this in web browser, so that will not work.

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't know that, maybe better to mention such things :)